# How to print timestamp with time zone to normal date in angular.js?

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular.js for font-end and node.js for server side.

Now, I am having some date format value in object.

Html code :

```
<html ng-app='myModule' ng-controller='mainController'>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="jumbotron">

      <span> Date : {{ months | date : 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <pre>{{ cleanData | json}}</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Controller code :

```
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter) {
$scope.months='2016-04-04T00:00:00.000Z' ;



}]);
```

Expexted output:

Date : 2016-04-04

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `Date` object into the date filter.

```
$scope.months = new Date('2016-04-04T00:00:00.000Z');
```

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/JkhcaqOnphn1QWxIsDdP?p=preview)